# Is cold temprature shock harmful for healthy people?

Tags: body-temperature, water-temperature, cryotherapy, air-temperature, middle-aged-adults

I often take cold showers and I also usually go under the cold water suddenly because I think it makes me stronger and makes me have more control over my nerves. I can imagine it could be bad for people with heart conditions but I'm talking about healthy mid-age people.

I was wondering if it is good or bad for healthy mid-age people to suddenly go under a shower with water temperature of around minimum 20 degree Celsius from room temperature of max 40 Celsius.

Comment: 20 C isn't even all that cold. People have been swimming in much colder water for thousands of years without harm.

Comment: @CareyGregory I know. But I believe 20 degrees sudden drop in temperature is not that little. I'm asking about the drop. Not about the cold. I think a sudden drop from 40 to 20 is breath taking for most people. I mean you can't easily breath so easily for a few seconds when that happens.